# Write without using pronouns extensively

Tags: pronouns, writing-style

I have just started learning English as my third language and struggling to write meaningful short essay without using pronouns extensively. I read mainly non-fiction English books and perhaps that has sort of instilled a certain thought patterns in me.

I am practicing to write a short self introduction and this issue becomes more noticeable. I used too many '***I***' and it appears egoistic.

I wonder if there are references and reading materials that I can read and learn to write differently? Or if there are any writing patterns to follow?

*Not into poetry though.*

Comment: You can camouflage some of the *I, I, I* by not beginning every sentence and paragraph with *I*.  For example: *English, my third language, is a new project for me.  In working on pronunciation, I've been finding the new "listen" feature in online dictionaries helpful.  But my teacher's advice, to look at my mouth with a small mirror while reciting a poem or singing a song in English, is actually what is helping the most.*

Comment: If you could include an example of a passage where you feel "I" is repetitive, it would be best. It would be easier to show you how to reduce that number, or we might disagree and say the number of instances  are perfectly fine.